# Program runs in Pycharm but not in terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, pycharm

I often run a program using terminal because that speeds things up by a factor of 3.  I recently upgraded from a 2016 version of Pycharm to a 2017 version and now I can no longer run the program in terminal.  The line that the terminal does not like is:

```
wb4 = load_workbook('../temp_proof.xlsx')
```

Again, this line works fine with Pycharm. I went to the terminal and made sure it was in the right directory and when I pressed ls, that file is in the directory.

```
Here is the terminal error message:
 File "/Users/bobsmith/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/prove.py", line 36, in <module>
    wb4 = load_workbook('../temp_proof.xlsx')

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 151, in load_workbook
    archive = _validate_archive(filename)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 115, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../temp_proof.xlsx'
```

Comment: it is obviously environment settings that are used in Pycharm and console are different; check both again, if it was working before check on pycharm side for project environment - may be notice some anomalies. I had issues as well when upgrading from 2016 to 2017 - they had some bugs in update process; one more solution - there is next 2017 upgrade - install that and if you still have 2016 conf alive use that.

Comment: the problem is with the place from where you are running the python file, try to pass the full path to the file inside the python program or keep the file in the same directory where you have you python file, then call the program

Comment: Drako, I do not know what you settings you mean.  Shouldn't terminal use all the settings that Pycharm does?  Exprator, I tried your solution and it does not work but thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens if in commandline (in the terminal where you try to run _python_, and it fails) you type: `ls ../temp_proof.xlsx`? If it fails (I think it should fail), you're in the "wrong" folder. Open *PyCharm*'s menu: _Run -> Edit Configurations..._, select your own (if more) and check _Working directory_. That is the path you should have in the terminal as well. Of course, the real solution would be not to use current directory relative paths in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons I had to put a slash in front of Users like so:

```
wb4 = load_workbook('/Users/bobsmith/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/temp_proof.xlsx')
```

I thought I tried that before, but this time it worked.  It also might be the case that I had to reconfigure my Pycharm working directory which I did. So I'm not sure what the real cause was.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to get the abs path from the temp_proof.xlsx file location. 
do this below steps

1. Go to the folder path temp_proof.xlsx
2. open python interpreter from that location and find the abs path to the location ie python 
   import os
   locpath=os.getcwd()
3. use locpath value to access temp_proof.xlsx file 
   ie filePath=os.path.join(locapth,'temp_proof.xlsx')
4. filePath you can use 
   wb4 = load_workbook(filePath)

This will work